# Display subcategories of custom categories - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, field, parent-child, categories

#### This is what I have:

```
    $args = array(
        'type' => 'post',
        'child_of' => 0,
        'parent' => '',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'exclude' => '',
        'include' => '',
        'number' => '',
        'taxonomy' => 'directory-category',
        'pad_counts' => false
    );
```

Which gets me the categories.

What I want is to get the child categories of this `directory-category` taxonomy.

Any ideas on how to do that?

> I'm not asking for a solution, just an advice or someone to show me the road.
>
> Googling didn't help :/

### Here is a screenshot [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0H5y.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you didn't want a direct answer, but essentially you want to use get_terms found here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

SELECT * from prod_term_taxonomy WHERE parent = 0;

UPDATE:

```
// Using your specific parent taxonomy id of 214 the query is below
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from prod_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'directory-category'");

// then you can use WordPress get_term to query each object to get it's name based on it's term_id. $results will be an array of objects so you will use a foreach loop to loop through to get each $result like this...

$child_cat_array = array();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $term = get_term( $result->term_id, $taxonomy );
    $name = $term->name;
    // the slug will be used for querying for posts
    $slug = $term->slug;
    // this will push the slug of the child category into the array for querying posts later
    array_push($child_cat_array, $slug);
}
```

You can then modify your get_posts query like this:

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'directory-category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $child_cat_array
        )
    )
);

$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Are you looking to get the posts associated with those child categories at all?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have already checked `get_terms()` but I was looking for something, just a bit more specific, lol

Comment: You may have to query the WordPress database with a global $wpdb. I can give you the answer if you'd like :) are you familiar with SQL? Because you would query for the exact table where they live in your WordPress database. There isn't a built in WordPress function for retrieving them unfortunately.

Comment: But again, are you trying to dynamically get all of the child tags or the posts associated with them, or both?

Comment: Well yeah, I am trying to get both. It would be very lovely if you could do that! Please do give me the answer if you can. Thank you

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? That will get the child categories you need and their term slug. Then you can use a tax_query that returns all of the posts associated with an array of the child categories slugs. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've tried adjusting your given answer with unfortunately no success.

Comment: Do you know what the id is of directory-category? What do you get when you var_dump and die on $results?

Comment: Check this [IMAGE HERE](http://imgur.com/a/MzDNH) out, the green outline. This could be of help.

Comment: So your taxonomy id was 214 so I put that into the query. Let me know what the var_dump and die on $results looks like.

Comment: var_dump returns `array(0) { }` and die returns just `Array`. Update: I've previously used this [LINK](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children#Examples) and it returned the subcategories

Comment: try this exact query instead $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from prod_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'directory-category'");

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I will try to figure it out myself from here as these comments are getting too long! I will update when I've figured it out or there's something. For now, you answer was very helpful, so I will mark it like so

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a list of Subcategories and the related posts based on a single category provided by you, you can use the following code. Make sure to use your own names of taxonomy, post_type and terms:

```
function ow_subcategories_with_posts_by_category( $taxonomy, $post_type, $term ) {
    $category = get_term_by( 'slug', $term, $taxonomy );
    $cat_id   = $category->term_id;

    // Get all subcategories related to the provided $category ($term)
    $subcategories = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
            'parent'     => $cat_id,
            'orderby'    => 'term_id',
            'hide_empty' => true
        )
    );
    ?>
    <div>
        <?php
        // Iterate through all subcategories to display each individual subcategory
        foreach ( $subcategories as $subcategory ) {

            $subcat_name = $subcategory->name;
            $subcat_id   = $subcategory->term_id;
            $subcat_slug = $subcategory->slug;

            // Display the name of each individual subcategory with ID and Slug
            echo '<h4>Subcategory: ' . $subcat_name . ' - ID: ' . $subcat_id . ' - Slug: ' . $subcat_slug  . '</h4>';

            // Get all posts that belong to this specific subcategory
            $posts = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type'      => $post_type,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1, // <-- Show all posts
                    'hide_empty'     => true,
                    'order'          => 'ASC',
                    'tax_query'      => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'terms'    => $subcat_id,
                            'field'    => 'id'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

            // If there are posts available within this subcategory
            if ( $posts->have_posts() ):
                ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    while ( $posts->have_posts() ): $posts->the_post();
                        //Show the title of each post with the Post ID
                        ?>
                        <li>Post: <?php the_title(); ?> - ID: <?php the_ID(); ?></li>
                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </ul>
                <?php
            else:
                echo 'No posts found';
            endif;

            wp_reset_query();
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
ow_subcategories_with_posts_by_category( 'name-of-your-taxonomy', 'name-of-your-post-type', 'name-of-your-specific-term' );
```

'name-of-your-taxonomy' is the name of the main taxonomy. e.g.: 'victual_category'

'name-of-your-post-type' is the name of your post type. e.g.: 'victual'

'name-of-your-specific-term' is the name of the specific category that you want to use so that subcategories that belong to that category can be displayed. e.g.: 'food'

So if I call the function:

```
ow_subcategories_with_posts_by_category( 'victual_category', 'victual', 'food' );
```

That would display all the subcategories with their respective Posts that belongs to Food of the Victual-Category taxonomy:

Subcategory: Appetizers - ID: 35 - Slug: appetizers

- Post: Chips & Salsa - ID: 464
- Post: Queso - ID: 465

Subcategory: Tacos - ID: 36 - Slug: tacos

- Post: Al Pastor - ID: 466
- Post: Fish Al Pastor - ID: 467